# To embed a chat in my site

Tags: chat, livechat, ape, ajax-push

I want to embed a chat in my site.The chat will be used for intercommunication between two members of site, like, the one used in social networking sites like facebook.  Can anyone suggest me which language i need to learn in order to make that work ?? Any link or reference to book will do.

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you will need to learn PHP + JScript + MySQL.

Comment: hmm.. i know basics of all of them.. But can you please specify how to start. it will be of great use. I have even used AJAX to create an online game

Comment: Using PHP, JSCRIPT and MYSQL will make my server too loaded and it will not be possible to cope up if there are number of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are some sample chat created with php javascript and mysql:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/

Comment: hey but d problem with this one is that this is a group chat. I wanna make a chat where user can communicate with their friends. I dont want the chat used for customer care etc,..

Comment: How exactly, users use cat. Have you site where you integrate it? Have your site users opportunity to create friend groups of something similar?

Comment: Hey ! In my site users are allowed to have account and friends and user can chat with each other..

Comment: If i use AJAX req every second to make the chat, i think it will end up with making my server busy. So, using AJAX for chat will not work good. So, please inform me if i have some alternatives

Comment: I think face book use ajax too, but how many users have on this site and how many of them will chat at same time eac other?

Comment: Hey I have made the chat using AJAX , but it may cause my server crash. So, I was thinking of some alternatives like APE etc. But I am having some problems in implementing that. So, I asked for some suggestions

Comment: I have implemented a basic chat using PHP, Jscript and Ajax.... But it doesnt seem satisfying to me... It may crash my server. So, i was searching for something like APE or any other suggestions....:)